# Странное поведение if-else

Tags: c#

Метод обрабатывает нажатие клавишы на клавиатуре (глобальный хук) и скрывает элементы на экране. Однако почему-то после активации `if(!SomeOpened)` сразу же активируется и блок `else`.

```
private static bool SomeOpened = false;
static private void _hook_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.M || e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
    {
        if (!SomeOpened)
        {
            form.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                form.Ellipse0.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                form.Point0.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            form.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                form.Ellipse0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                form.Point0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }));
        }
        SomeOpened = !SomeOpened;
    }
}
```

Либо у меня глюки, либо такого быть не должно...

Comment: С `if-else` это вообще никак не связано. Хук на то и хук, что может быть вызван в любое время. Просто пока у Вас отрабатывает основная ветка, хук вызывается снова и срабатывает уже ветка `else`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Дисклеймер**

Данный вопрос является очень "ситуационным", как выяснилось в обсуждении, у автора где-то неявно происходит создание второго инстанса класса с точно таким же обработчиком такого события (это было выяснено путем сравнения this этих объектов). Поскольку поиск по коду ничего не дал - было принято сделать "костыльное решение" с `e.Handled = true`. Для всех последующих пользователей: если вы столкнулись с похожей проблемой - вы, скорее всего, подписали два одинаковых обработчика из-за копии класса, например.

```
private static bool SomeOpened = false;
private void _hook_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (LastWindowIsTABG)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.M || e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            if (!SomeOpened)
            {
                form.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    form.Ellipse0.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    form.Point0.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                form.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    form.Ellipse0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    form.Point0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }));
            }

            SomeOpened = !SomeOpened;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: У меня идет обработка сыбытия *KeyUp*, *KeyDown* я не обрабатываю.

Comment: @skproch, моя ошибка, я по своему опыту с С++ судил, там событие было одно на KeyUp и KeyDown. Прошу прощение за эту оплошность, впоследствии удалю этот бессмысленный ответ.

Comment: А как работает `&&` в `if (&& LastWindowIsTABG)`?

Comment: @gil9red опечатка, благодарю за замечание :)

Answer (score 1):

логика, ты где

```
SomeOpened -  что-то открыто
if (!SomeOpened) Visibility.Hidden - если не открыто прячем

if (!) else - тоже странная конструкция
```

а это

```
    if (SomeOpened)
        SomeOpened = false;
    else
        SomeOpened = true;
```

нельзя записать так?

```
SomeOpened = !SomeOpened
```

---

```
private static bool SomeOpened = false;
static private void _hook_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (LastWindowIsTABG && (e.KeyCode == Keys.M || e.KeyCode == Keys.E))
    {
        if (SomeOpened)
        {
            form.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                form.Ellipse0.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                form.Point0.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            form.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                form.Ellipse0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                form.Point0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }));
        }

        SomeOpened = !SomeOpened;

    }    
}
```

---

далее предположение глядя на доки

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

и

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907638/4794368

переменная и функция должны быть экземпляром объекта а не конструктора, то есть `static` - лишний.

так же можно завесть счётчик. который будет увеличиваться при каждом вызове `_hook_KeyUp` и сравнивать соответствует ли он "нажатию".

в общем должно получиться как-то так

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    LowLevelKeyboardHook hook;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        hook = new LowLevelKeyboardHook();

        hook.KeyUp += _hook_KeyUp;
    }

    private bool SomeOpened = true;
    private void _hook_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LastWindowIsTABG && (e.KeyCode == Keys.M || e.KeyCode == Keys.E))
        {
            if (SomeOpened)
            {
                form.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    form.Ellipse0.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    form.Point0.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                form.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    form.Ellipse0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    form.Point0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }));
            }

            SomeOpened = !SomeOpened;

        }    
    }


}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81564/discussion-on-answer-by-qwabra---if-else).